# Discord.js Audit logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

been owning a discord bot for quite a while and I decided it's time to make a lot of logging options (everything can be toggled via a database etc)

I have been looking at the discord development page but can't quite figure out how those events work, as I tried for example to use the "CHANNEL_CREATE" event and make it console.log something, though it doesn't even after creating a channel.

```
client.on('CHANNEL_CREATE', async () => {
console.log('New channel created')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those aren't the events you looking for.
You need to look at the events on Discord.JS documentation: [Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-channelCreate).
And you're looking for the event `channelCreate`:

```
client.on('channelCreate', channel => {
    console.log("Channel with ID: " + channel.id + " was just created");
});
```